# Simple Navigation and dynamic items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, navigation

I'm using simple-navigation to dynamically generate my navigation depending on a permission level that the user has. It works fine but it doesn't seem to mark any item as current.
Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `highlights_on` if its not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that it needs the absolute path from the root, not the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the 'Highlighting the active Navigation Item' section here: https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation/wiki/Configuration